# Boost unit test framework without test cases

Tags: c++, boost

I have a testing program in which I'd like to make use of the boost testing tools. This program is however not a series of unit tests, and I need access to the arguments passed to the `main` function. Previously I've used the `minimal.hpp` file, but this has a significant limitation that it always defines `main` and thus can't be included in multiple files. It also has a limited set of testing tools.

How can I use the boost testing macros without using unit test cases? I already know how to use my own main function can call the unit test library (using `unit_test_main`), but I don't recall where the documentation for that is and what I can pass to it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to keep using test cases. At least one ;o)

You can access command line arguments through framework::master_test_suite().argc, framework::master_test_suite().argv. You can read more details [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/master-test-suite.html).